# Purpose of invoke_* functions generated by emscripten

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

When compiling to WebAssembly, emscripten generates functions like `invoke_vii`. What is their purpose?

**Details:**

WebAssembly modules compiled from C with `emcc -s WASM=1 -g` expect various functions to be provided by the host environment.

```
...
(import "env" "abortOnCannotGrowMemory" (func $import$9 (result i32)))
(import "env" "invoke_vii" (func $import$10 (param i32 i32 i32)))
(import "env" "___syscall221" (func $import$11 (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
...
```

I am working on a WebAssembly interpreter written in C. So I have to deal with providing these functions, but I am dumbfounded by functions like `invoke_vii`, `invoke_iiii`, and the like.

The postfix is obviously related to the call signature. For example, `vii` means return `void` and take some `int`s. The name *invoke* suggests the function is supposed to invoke something.

I could find no information about these functions other than their implementation in the Java Script code generated by emscripten:

```
function invoke_ii(index,a1) {
  # removed error checking for brevity
  return Module["dynCall_ii"](index,a1);
}
```

`dynCall_ii` exists in the WebAssembly module.

It seems all the `invoke_*` functions do is to instruct the interpreter to run the corresponding `dynCall_*` function. What is the purpose of this indirection? Why doesn't the WebAssembly code call `dynCall_` directly?

Comment: It seems to be something to do with function pointers in C.

Comment: Hmm.. I also thought this, but WebAssembly has function pointer support specced in with tables and indirect calls. Now I rather believe this is for setting up longjumps, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are used for handling of setjmp/longjmp and also C++ exceptions.   In these mechanisms JavaScript requires the ability to call back into a WebAssembly and invoke functions in the WebAssembly indirect function table.

If you build without exceptions and with `-s SUPPORT_LONGJMP=0` (not the default) you should not see any these functions at all.

Comment: Oh I should note that it is specifically try/catch that you see in the invoke functions that are the reason they need to be written in JavaScript because WebAssembly itself has no ability to non-local control flow such as longjmp or exceptions on its own today.